# Using debugger in Java can I access Assembly code (OPCODE) and change it?

Tags: java, debugging, memory, assembly, opcode

I have a java program loaded in the memory. Using a Java debugger at runtime, can I access the assembly code and change the next OPCODE and then rerun the program? Please let me know if this is feasible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you're really trying to do, and we'll tell you a proper way to do it. Java isn't really suited for this kind of thing, so I'd advise you to move to C or C++.

Comment: I am trying to create a fault injector with Java. I want to corrupt the OPCODE and DATA in memory while the program is running and loaded into the memory. This I want to do with Java.

Comment: in Java it's bytecode, not assembly. The JIT (JVM) will convert the bytecode into machine code which can be disassembled into assembly

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do the dis assembly and then change selected lines in bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about editing it but with the java compiler you can certainly generate it with something like

`javac MyClass.java`

javap -c MyClass > MyClass.bc

here is a good article to understand it from
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/

I imagine there is a way to change it then recompile with javap

**edit**
There are apparently some open source compilers for java byte code see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmin_%28Java_assembler%29

Answer (score 0):

You can alter bytecode at runtime using a library such as javassist. Have a look:

http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

Answer (score 0):

Which debugger are you using? If you use Eclipse IDE you can alter the code even when the program is already running without the need of stopping it. This can only be done if no interfaces of the class are affected, though.

So the short answer to your question is: Yes, it can be done.

But it depends on your debugger implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using any debugger right now. I know this thing can be implemented with the help of WinDBG in .Net. Hence, I am looking for a debugger. I want to write an independent program, which will access the memory. Do you know which debugger and other tools I need to use for this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know this, but since Eclipse is OpenSource and basically does what you want to do, I would take a look at it.